# How can I install Foundation for Sites correctly with npm?

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation

I would like to create a template based on the Foundation Zurb template which can be updated easily. So my first thought was to use `npm` to get the package and specific versions.

The ["Foundation for Sites" documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) says that Foundation can be installed with the command:
`npm install foundation-sites`.

If I call this command in an empty directory I get the following output:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/robert/Documents/blog/src/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/robert/Documents/blog/src/package.json'
npm WARN src No description
npm WARN src No repository field.
npm WARN src No README data
npm WARN src No license field.

+ foundation-sites@6.4.3
```

Afterwards I see the following files/directories:

```
node_modules/
package-lock.json
```

From the documentation I would have expected this:

[image: Package contents]

It occurs to me that I'm missing some understanding.

Is that a reasonable way to "build" the package?

Answer (score 0):

npm installs dependencies into `node_modules`.

You want to use one of the templates eg https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template or https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template which you can install using `foundation-cli`.